# query xml date nodes using jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, date

I have the following xml which is just shift patterns structured over x weeks, days, shift start dates and end dates. I need to query the xml to change the content of a div during that shift time in that week if my xml node "enabled is true".

e.g. 'week1' 'Monday' 'Date' 'shift starts' 'shift ends' 'enabled = true' then change the content (html) of a div to during that shift.

XML sample Schedule below:

```
<Schedule>
  <Week2>
    <StartDate>2012-07-30T00:00:00</StartDate> <!-- Week Beginning -->
        <Shift>
            <Date>2012-07-30T00:00:00</Date> <!-- Monday -->
            <StartTime>2012-07-30T09:45</StartTime> <!-- Shift Starts -->
            <EndTime>2012-07-30T17:45</EndTime> <!-- Shift Ends -->
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        </Shift>
        <Shift>
            <Date>2012-07-31T00:00:00</Date> <!-- Tuesday -->
            <StartTime>2012-07-31T09:45</StartTime> <!-- Shift Starts -->
            <EndTime>2012-07-31T17:45</EndTime> <!-- Shift Ends -->
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        </Shift>
        <Shift>
            <Date>2012-08-01T00:00:00</Date> <!-- Wednesday -->
            <StartTime></StartTime> <!-- Shift Starts -->
            <EndTime></EndTime> <!-- Shift Ends -->
            <Enabled>false</Enabled>
        </Shift>
        <Shift>
            <Date>2012-08-02T00:00:00</Date> <!-- Thursday -->
            <StartTime>2012-08-02T09:45</StartTime> <!-- Shift Starts -->
            <EndTime>2012-08-02T17:45</EndTime> <!-- Shift Ends -->
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        </Shift>
        <Shift>
            <Date>2012-08-03T00:00:00</Date> <!-- Friday -->
            <StartTime>2012-08-03T09:45</StartTime> <!-- Shift Starts -->
            <EndTime>2012-08-03T17:45</EndTime> <!-- Shift Ends -->
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        </Shift>
        <Shift>
            <Date>2012-08-04T00:00:00</Date> <!-- Saturday -->
            <StartTime>2012-08-04T08:15</StartTime> <!-- Shift Starts -->
            <EndTime>2012-08-04T16:45</EndTime> <!-- Shift Ends -->
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        </Shift>
        <Shift>
            <Date>2012-08-05T00:00:00</Date> <!-- Sunday -->
            <StartTime></StartTime> <!-- Shift Starts -->
            <EndTime></EndTime> <!-- Shift Ends -->
            <Enabled>false</Enabled>
        </Shift>
  </Week2>
</Schedule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var xml = "our xml...";

    var resultArray = 
    $(xml).find('Enabled:contains(true)')
        .parent()
        .map(function(item){
            return {
              date: $(this).children('Date').text(),
              startTime: $(this).children('StartTime').text()
              // and so on ....
            }
        })).get();
```

parent will return collection of shift objects. If you need week then use 'parents' and specify the Week2, then look descendants as in example.